# regex facebook url

Tags: regex

Im try scrape profile facebook from facebook mobile.
im use this regex :

> href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)

RESULTS :

> href="/bookmarks/get.php?partial=1&refid=8 href="/krakiun?refid=8
>   href="/home.php?refid=8 href="/messages/?ref=bookmark&refid=8
>   href="/places/nearbyfriends.php?ref=bookmark&refid=8
>   href="/events/?ref=bookmark&refid=8
>   href="/friends/?ref=bookmark&refid=8 href="/sblocconet?refid=60
>   href="/protrucchicom?refid=60
>   href="/profile.php?id=133284666701857&refid=60
>   href="/profile.php?id=324052547642490&refid=60
>   href="/profile.php?id=426388387443355&refid=60
>   href="/groups/149801558421820?ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/groups/297121487026176?ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/bookmarks/get.php?bookmarktype=group&refid=60 href="#
>   href="/pages?ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/appcenter/?ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/buddylist.php?ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/findfriends/browser/?ref=bookmark&fb_ref=tn&refid=60
>   href="/home.php?sk=photodash&ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/apps/cupidcom?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmark&app_id=277669328975&refid=60 href="/bookmarks/get.php?bookmarktype=app&refid=60
>   href="/home.php?sk=fl_1852388924315&ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/bookmarks/get.php?bookmarktype=friend_list&refid=60
>   href="/home.php?sk=fl_1960883876621&ref=bookmark&refid=60
>   href="/help/?refid=8 href="/settings/?refid=8 href="/policies/?refid=8
>   href="/bugnub/?refid=8
>   href="/logout.php?h=AffXaycUfvR1ir-V&t=1362313180&refid=8
>   href="/language.php?refid=8
>   href="https://www.facebook.com/?m2w&refid=8
>   href="#partial-side-menu href="/friends/requests.php?refid=8
>   href="/daniel.mihalcea.58?fref=m_jewel&refid=8
>   href="/daniel.mihalcea.58?fref=m_jewel&refid=8
>   href="/sandra.bira.3?fref=m_jewel&refid=8
>   href="/sandra.bira.3?fref=m_jewel&refid=8
>   href="/ayda.ringelberg?fref=m_jewel&refid=8
>   href="/ayda.ringelberg?fref=m_jewel&refid=8
>   href="/ayda.and.jacco.P.R?refid=8
>   href="/friends/requests.php?v=all-requests&refid=8
>   href="/messages/?refid=8 href="/messages/compose/?refid=8
>   href="/messages/read/?tid=id.473135699369224
>   href="/messages/read/?tid=id.276586722374866
>   href="/messages/read/?tid=id.411179178903782
>   href="/messages/read/?tid=lVO86WNhFDuKhNa9YeWyjg
>   href="/messages/read/?tid=X6Q0PlBMpsp6324Vj5W1SA
>   href="/messages/read/?tid=id.123727074422514 href="/messages/?refid=8
>   href="/notifications.php?refid=8
>   href="/krakiun?v=approval&highlight=500002920037309&ref=m_notif&notif_t=photo_tag&actorid=100000828157260#500002920037309
>   href="/photo.php?fbid=491923467540375&id=100001681789779&set=a.347981525267904.89812.100001681789779&ref=m_notif&notif_t=backdated_content&actorid=100001681789779
>   href="/krakiun?v=approval&highlight=491923467540375&ref=m_notif&notif_t=photo_tag&actorid=100001681789779#491923467540375
>   href="/sblocconet?ref=m_notif&notif_t=page_new_likes&actorid=100000960089496
>   href="/sblocconet?sk=messages_inbox&ref=m_notif&notif_t=fbpage_new_message&actorid=125839484261145
>   href="/notifications.php?more&refid=8
>   href="/search/?query=krakiun&search=people&o=2048&ssid=420259245&refid=46
>   href="/search/?query=krakiun&search=page&o=65&ssid=420259245&refid=46
>   href="/search/?query=krakiun&search=event&o=4&ssid=420259245&refid=46
>   href="/search/?query=krakiun&search=group&o=69&ssid=420259245&refid=46
>   href="/krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=0&st=self&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/bogdan.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=1&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/a/mobile/friends/add_friend.php?id=100005027372212&hf=search&gfid=AQALGuxrtyF4_IYW&refid=46
>   href="/copilau.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=2&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/a/mobile/friends/add_friend.php?id=100002482301062&hf=search&gfid=AQB1qH2svv9ZAuBY&refid=46
>   href="/viktor.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=3&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/a/mobile/friends/add_friend.php?id=100003653628437&hf=search&gfid=AQBxpBokNInneuaI&refid=46
>   href="/iokeni.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=4&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/search/?query=krakiun&search=object&ssid=420259245&s=5&refid=46
>   href="/search/?query=krakiun&search=friends&ssid=420259245&refid=46
>   href="/search/?query=krakiun&search=everyone&ssid=420259245&refid=46
>   href="#

working bat extract all url from page, bat i need only profile link :

> href="/bogdan.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=1&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/copilau.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=2&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/viktor.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=3&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46
>   href="/iokeni.krakiun?slog=420259245&seq=2109322985&rk=4&st=user&fbtype=2048&refid=46

im use regex whit ubotstudio, please help me to modify this regex, because I am not able ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only match urls containing `?slog=`

```
href=[\'"]?([^\'" >?]+\?slog=[^\'" >]+)
```

Comment: how can be extracted only up to slog without the rest of the link.
essample :
href="/bogdan.krakiun?slog

Comment: @krakiun. `href=[\'"]?[^\'" >?]+\?slog`, or if you don't want to include the `?slog=` you could use `href=[\'"]?[^\'" >?]+(?=\?slog=)`.